# Publishing an application via Visual Studio to Azure Service Fabric (Azure Gov) with Azure Active Directory Authentication

Tags: visual-studio, azure-active-directory, azure-service-fabric

I have deployed Azure Service Fabric (6.1) in Azure Gov using custom ARM templates which utilize an Azure Active Directory Tenant for authenticating users performing management tasks such as accessing the Service Fabric Explorer and publishing applications to the fabric.

The templates seem to have worked beautifully, as I can point a browser to https://fqdn:19080/Explorer/index.html and immediately I'm prompted for the Azure AD credentials.  Upon providing those credentials, the Service Fabric Explorer is presented as expected.

The issue I am having is with Visual Studio Community 2017 (15.5.6).  When attempting to publish an application to the Service Fabric, in my case the [GettingStartedApplication](https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-services-and-actors-dotnet) from Github, the Azure AD authentication window is presented, and then unexpectedly vanishes a few short seconds later.  This happens on the 'Publish Service Fabric Application' window within VS.  Within this window, there is also a drop-down for 'Connection Endpoint', which is where you enter fqdn:19000.  If VS is able to contact the Service Fabric, you'll see a green check appear.  In my case, when it contacts that FQDN, that is when I'm initially prompted to log in.

In each case when I have attempted to publish this application, the Azure AD authentication window displays and then vanishes, as noted above.  I can click 'Publish' anyway and it begins to build the deployment.  Oddly, after a few seconds, the Azure AD authentication window displays again--and once again, after a very brief moment (around 3 seconds), it unexpectedly closes.  In some cases, I have been able to enter my username and password quickly enough that it then goes on to the next step--entering a pin number for 2-factor authentication.  I'll even actually receive the text message with my pin, but by the time I go to enter it, the Azure AD authentication window has suddenly closed again.

- On a side note, 2-factor authentication is not an issue for accessing the Service Fabric Explorer; again, that part is working great.

There was **one** instance where I was able to enter everything quickly enough, including the pin, **without** losing the authentication window.  The application actually published successfully.  Bear in mind, this is out of say a dozen or so attempts.

Any idea what might be happening here?

Answer (score 0):

This was apparently being caused by a timer setting within the project itself to cap out at 10 seconds.

I did some experimenting with Connect-ServiceFabricCluster via Powershell and when I forced -TimeoutSec to 10, I found that the authentication window behaved almost identically to what I was experiencing within VS as originally described.

I then added a TimeoutSec option to  in Cloud.xml for the VS project and set it to 120 seconds--vanishing authentication window issue resolved.

I reckon 10 seconds is not enough time for the initial authentication request to pop, allow the user to enter the creds, wait, receive a text for 2-factor, and then finally authenticate with the second authenticator.  30 seconds is probably fairly reasonable.